# Failed to load library tidyr in R (version 4.1)

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I need to use the functions `spread` and `gather` in the package of `tidyr`, and I installed this package. I also installed two other packages. However, when I tried to use `library(tidyr)`, it gave me this long error message, basically saying `tidyr` was not successfully loaded. By the way, my R is a newer version (4.1). Thanks!

```
install.packages("tidyr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("devtools")
```

Here's the error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
> undefined exports: align, char, colonnade, ctl_new_pillar, ctl_new_pillar_list, dim_desc, expect_known_display, extra_cols, format_glimpse, format_type_sum, get_extent, get_max_extent, glimpse, is_vector_s3, new_ornament, new_pillar, new_pillar_component, new_pillar_shaft, new_pillar_shaft_simple, new_pillar_title, new_pillar_type, num, obj_sum, pillar, pillar_component, pillar_shaft, scale_x_num, scale_y_num, set_char_opts, set_num_opts, size_sum, squeeze, style_bold, style_na, style_neg, style_num, style_subtle, style_subtle_num, tbl_format_body, tbl_format_footer, tbl_format_header, tbl_format_setup, tbl_sum, type_sum
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: package ‘tidyr’ was built under R version 4.1.2
> 2: S3 methods ‘as_tbl.data.frame’, ‘ctl_new_pillar.tbl’, ‘ctl_new_pillar_list.tbl’, ‘extra_cols.pillar_squeezed_colonnade’, ‘format.pillar’, ‘format.pillar_1e’, ‘format.pillar_capital’, ‘format.pillar_char’, ‘format.pillar_char_attr’, ‘format.pillar_colonnade’, ‘format.pillar_continuation_shaft’, ‘format.pillar_num’, ‘format.pillar_num_attr’, ‘format.pillar_ornament’, ‘format.pillar_rif_shaft’, ‘format.pillar_rif_title’, ‘format.pillar_rif_type’, ‘format.pillar_shaft’, ‘format.pillar_shaft_decimal’, ‘format.pillar_shaft_simple’, ‘format.pillar_squeezed_colonnade’, ‘format.pillar_tbl_format_setup’, ‘format.pillar_title’, ‘format.pillar_type’, ‘format.tbl’, ‘format_glimpse.character’, ‘format_glimpse.default’, ‘format_glimpse.factor’, ‘format_glimpse.list’, ‘format_type_sum.AsIs’, ‘format_type_sum.default’, ‘glimpse.data.frame’, ‘glimpse.default’, ‘glimpse.tbl’, ‘obj_print_data.pillar_vctr’, ‘obj_print_footer.pillar_vctr’, ‘obj_print_header.pillar_vctr’, ‘obj_sum.AsIs’, ‘obj_sum.default’, ‘ [... truncated]

Comment: By the way, `spread` and `gather` have been superseded by `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Thanks. What package do I use for pivot_wider and pivot_longer?

Comment: `tidyr`.  They are direct replacements for `spread` and `gather`.  Details in the online doc or (since you're having trouble installing `tidyr`) [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).

Comment: Also, loading the whole tidyverse makes loading tidyr in particular unnessecary. tidyr package is part of loading the tidyverse.